# What's wrong with my attempt to print a triangle made of asterisk characters?

Tags: scheme

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6pni.png)

i have tried this but its not working

```
(define (print x)
    (cond
        ((< x 0) #t)
        ((> x 0) (display "*"))
        ((= x 0) (newline))
        ((> x 0) (print (- x 1)))
        )
    )
(define (printA x)
    (cond
        ((< x 0) 1)
        ((> x 0) (print x))
        ((= x 0) (print x))
        )
    (printA (- x 1))
    )
    
(printA 5)
```

Comment: What kind of Scheme do you use (eg. R5RS or Racket)? If this is homework, are there any functions you aren't allowed to use?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "its not working"?  When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing that doesn't behave as you expected?

Comment: BTW: drop the habit of placing parentheses as if you were programming in a "braces and semicolons" language. Scheme is not structured in blocks like that, and it only gets confusing and causes bugs.

Answer (score 0):

`print` never recurses - a `cond` only evaluates the first matching clause, not all of them.

In other words, your function is equivalent to

```
(define (print x)
    (cond
        ((< x 0) #t)
        ((> x 0) (display "*"))
        ((= x 0) (newline))))
```

You need to recurse in the matching clause.

```
(define (print x)
    (cond
        ((> x 0) (display "*") (print (- x 1)))
        ((= x 0) (newline))
        (else #t)))
```

(I rearranged the clauses to put the "interesting" clauses first and the boring "everything else" clause last.)

`printA` is broken for the "opposite" reason - it *always* recurses and will never terminate.
You need to recurse only in the appropriate clause, not after the `cond` has been evaluated.
(You should also not print anything for the zero case.)

A first attempt might be

```
(define (printA x)
    (cond
        ((> x 0) (print x) (printA (- x 1)))
        (else 1)))
```

but...

```
> (printA 4)
****
***
**
*
1
```

... it prints in the wrong order.
(And the `1` looks weird, but let's not worry about that now.)

Fortunately, this isn't hard to fix - you just print the shorter line before "this line" instead of after:

```
(define (printA x)
    (cond
        ((> x 0) (printA (- x 1)) (print x))
        (else 1)))
```

```
> (printA 4)
*
**
***
****
```